# Encoding detection library in python

Tags: python, html, xml, http, character-encoding

This is somehow related to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305997/unicodedecodeerror-problem-with-mechanize).

I process tons of texts (in HTML and XML mainly) fetched via HTTP. I'm looking for a library in python that can do smart encoding detection based on different strategies and convert texts to unicode using best possible character encoding guess.

I found that [chardet](http://chardet.feedparser.org) does auto-detection extremely well. However auto-detecting everything is the problem because it is SLOW and very much against all standards. As per `chardet` [FAQ](http://chardet.feedparser.org/docs/faq.html#faq.yippie) I don't want to screw the standards.

From the same FAQ here is the list of places where I want to look for encoding:

- charset parameter in HTTP `Content-type` header.
- `<meta http-equiv="content-type">` element in 
  the `<head>` of a web page for HTML
  documents.
- encoding attribute in the XML prolog for XML
  documents.
- Auto-detect the character encoding as a last resort.

Basically I want to be able to look in all those place and also deal with conflicting information automatically.

Is there such library out there or do I need to write it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeautifulSoup (the html parser) incorporates a class called UnicodeDammit that does just that. Have a look and see if you like it.

Comment: It looks very promising. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)'s [UnicodeDammit](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit), which in turn uses [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet).

`chardet` by itself is quite useful for the general case (determining text's encoding) but slow as you say. `UnicodeDammit` adds extra features on top of `chardet`, in particular that it can look up the encoding explicitly specified in XML's encoding tags.

As for the HTTP `Content-type` header, I think you need to read that yourself to extract the `charset` parameter, and then pass it to `UnicodeDammit` in the `fromEncoding` parameter.

As for resolving conflicts, UnicodeDammit will give precedence to explicitly-stated encoding (if the encoding doesn't generate errors). See the docs for full details.

Comment: [cchardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cchardet/) (https://github.com/PyYoshi/cChardet) is a faster native code dropin replacement for  `chardet`.